# Is $\int_\gamma k_g ds =0$ for any shortest simple closed curve $\gamma$ dividing $S^2$ into two equal parts?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Consider a smooth Riemannian manifold $(S^2,g)$, where $S^2$ is the topological sphere. $\gamma$ is the shortest simple closed curve which dividing $S^2$ to two parts and the two parts have equal areas (as shown in the figure below, where $A_1=A_2$).  Then, whether there is
$$
\int_\gamma k_g ds =0  
$$
where $k_g$ is the geodesic curvature. And how to show it?

> [image]

PS(2023-7-24): In Kurt G.'s answer, I feel there is a way to keep the  equator is the shortest curve.

When $f^2\le \sin^2\theta$ (not always equal), then the shortest curve maybe not the equator.

> [image]

But when $f^2\ge \sin^2\theta$, the shortest curve should be the equator.

> [image]

The $f(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$ is not keypoint, it just be used to keep the equators of $(S^2,g)$ and unit sphere are same.

In fact, I think the $\int_\gamma k_g ds =0$ should be wrong in general.
Although  I didn't quite get  the Deane's comment, but I get an idea. Consider a surface liking dumbbell (picture below). At beginning, $A_1=A_2$, suppose at beginning, $k_g\equiv0$ on the black curve. Then, we enlarge  $A_2$ a little. So, the curve must move right. When $A_2-A_1$ is enough small, the black curve doesn't rotate without translating, since after rotate, the curve elongate more than after translating. Therefore, we can structure a pipe (the middle part of dumbbell) which only at a meridian $k_g\equiv 0$. So, when it move right, there is not $\int k_g ds =0$.

Besides, I even suspect that $k_g$ is constant maybe wrong. Since we can strcture some special crease on the pipe such that after moving right, the $k_g$ of curve is not constant. But, about this, I am very unclear.

> [image]

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: @KurtG.  For such curve,  is there $\int_\gamma k_g ds =0$ ?

Comment: You said that $\gamma$ is a geodesic. Then its [geodesic curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_curvature) $k_g$ is zero.

Comment: @KurtG.  Why it is geodesic ?  $\gamma$ is the shortest one among  curves dividing $S^2$  to equal two parts.

Comment: $S^2$ is the unit sphere and its geodesics are great circles. So your $\gamma$ is a geodesic.

Comment: @KurtG.  I say $S^2$ is topological sphere,  not unit sphere...  And my picture is not a round sphere.

Comment: I believe that $\gamma$ has constant geodesic curvature, which does not have to be zero. A good special case to work out, even though it is not smooth is a a finite circular cone (i.e., a circular pyramid). I don't know a short way to derive this, but you can find the derivation of the the higher dimensional version of this, where you minimize the surface area of the boundary of a domain while keeping the volume of the domain fixed, in many places.

Comment: @Deane Although I don't fully understand you, I feel you are right. Since in some paper (maybe Hamilton's), I see the Cheeger set of surface have constant geodesic curvature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it now the question is quite interesting and I think
it is generally not true that $\int_\gamma k_g\,ds=0\,.$
By the example below the geodesic curvature $k_g$ is not identically zero
on a curve that divides the surface into two parts of equal area:

***What we know:***

On the unit sphere $S^2$ in polar coordinates, $\theta$ polar angle, $\varphi$ azimuthal angle, the standard metric is
$$
g=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\sin^2\theta\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
The equator $\{\theta=\pi/2\}$ is a geodesic because is is a great circle and it
divides the sphere into two equal parts whose area is $2\pi$ each.

***Modification:***

We equip the sphere with the metric
$$
h=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&f^2(\theta)\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $f$ is a function satisfying the conditions
$$\tag{1}
f(0)=f(\pi)=0\,,\quad f'(0)=-f'(\pi)=1\,,\quad f^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n)}(\pi)=0\,,\; \forall n\text{ even, }
$$
of Ch. 1, section 3.4 of [1]. (As pointed out by mollyerin
we need this to have a smooth metric on $S^2\,.$)

Let's also assume that $f>0$ on $(0,\pi)\,.$

The non zero Christoffel symbols are
\begin{align}
%\Gamma_{\varphi\theta\varphi}&=\Gamma_{\phi\theta\varphi}=f(\theta)f'(\theta)\,,
%&\Gamma_{\theta\varphi\varphi}&=-f(\theta)f'(\theta)\,,\\
{\Gamma^\varphi}_{\theta\varphi}&={\Gamma^\varphi}_{\theta\varphi}=\frac{f'(\theta)}{f(\theta)}\,,
&{\Gamma^\theta}_{\varphi\varphi}&=-f(\theta)f'(\theta)\,.
\end{align}
The geodesic equations $\ddot\theta + \Gamma^\theta_{\varphi\varphi}\dot\varphi\dot\varphi=0=\ddot\varphi+2\,\Gamma^\varphi_{\theta\varphi}\dot\theta\dot\varphi$ are then
\begin{align}
0&=\ddot \theta-f(\theta)f'(\theta)\,\dot\varphi^2\,,&
0&=\ddot\varphi+\frac{2f'(\theta)\,\dot\theta\,\dot\varphi}{f(\theta)}\,.
\end{align}
The first equation shows directly that a latitude $\{\theta=\text{const}\}$ with $\theta\not\in\{0,\pi\}$ is a geodesic
only when $f'(\theta)=0\,.$

The area of the part of the sphere that lies between $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ is
$$
S(\theta_1,\theta_2)=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}f(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\varphi=2\pi\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}f(\theta)\,d\theta\,.
$$
The latitude $\theta^*$ that divides the sphere into two parts of equal area is defined by
$$
2S(0,\theta^*)=S(0,\pi)\,.
$$
I believe there exist many functions $f$ that satisfy the
requirements (1) where $f'(\theta^*)$ is not zero. Asymmetric
perturbations of the classic $f(\theta)=\sin\theta$ should probably work.

Each such case is an example where the curve consisting of the latitude dividing the sphere
into two equal parts is not a geodesic and therefore does not have geodesic curvature $k_g$ zero.

[1] P. Petersen, *Riemannian Geometry.*

Comment: I don't quite see why this is a metric on the sphere; the length of latitudes continue to grow as $\theta \to \infty$, so it's unclear to me how to extend your metric to $\mathbb{S}^2$. (It seems like you have a coherent metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and are just doing calculations on the ball of radius $\pi$ about $0$.)

Comment: Note that I think the general idea is correct and the top-level claim is indeed false, and a rotationally-symmetric metric will serve as a counterexample. E.g. the cone has a latitude around its conical axis that splits the area but doesn't have zero average geodesic curvature (it bends in the direction of the point).

Comment: @mollyerin I think you are right and the cone is probably a much simpler counter example. Thanks for the input !  Learned again a lot today. If I may just ask one question: if $\theta$ is restricted to $[0,\pi]$ why is $h$ not a metric on $S^2$ ?

Comment: In your metric on $(\theta, \phi) \in [0, \pi] \times [0, 2\pi]$, the curve $\theta = \pi$ has length $2\pi^3$ (and so in particular can't possibly be a point). In order for a metric on this rectangle to pass to the sphere, it had better at least assign $0$ length to the two curves $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = \pi$.

Comment: BTW, There is a nice characterization of when metrics of the form $dt^2 + \phi(t)^2 d\theta$ on $[0, a] \times \mathbb{S}^1$ will give rise to smooth metrics on $\mathbb{S}^2$, namely: $\phi(0) = \phi(a) = 0$, $\dot{\phi}(0) = 1, \dot{\phi}(a) = -1$, and all the even derivatives of $\phi$ should vanish at $0$ and $1$. This is done in Ch. 1, section 3.4 of Petersen's book, for instance.

Comment: @mollyerin Many thanks. Totally convincing and now taken into account.

Comment: This is a very nice idea (+1). However, nothing guarantees that the constructed curve is a shortest one separating the sphere in two pieces of same area

Comment: @Didier This is also correct and I was thinking about it. Nonetheless it was a fruitful day already and one should never work harder than the client. :)

Comment: @Didier  For the $\theta^*=\frac{\pi}{2}$, I think $f^2(\theta)\ge \sin^2\theta, f(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$ can guarantee the equator be the shortest one.  But my think is not exact, I have add some picture in my problem to describ it.  But the condition I adding imply $f'(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$.

Comment: Wonderful construction. Though it is not perfect, I believe that  $\int k_g ds=0 $  is generally not true. Thanks.

Comment: @lanse7pty I also thank you for coming up with the question and engaging in the discussion. As Didier pointed out we don't know if there is not a shorter curve (in the metric $h$) or even a geodesic that half-divides the sphere. All we know so far is that this curve cannot be a latitude. It is probably worth to work on this problem further.

Comment: @KurtG.  Could you understand what Deane's saying (in the comment above)?  He always tell me the right thing in my experience. But I can't understant it well. And, this problem comes from my calculation about Cheeger constant. In fact, in Hamilton's An Isoperimetric Estimate for the Ricci Flow on the Two-Sphere, Hamilton state that the Cheeger set  have constant geodesic curvature in 243th page. He said using standard variantional, but he didn't give detail proof.  I feel the proof Hamilton mentioned should be useful.

Comment: Besides, Deane was contemporary with Hamilton, he should be familiar with what Hamilton mentioned. So, I think, follow he said, there should be a right way.

Comment: @lanse7pty Deane is surely a much better expert than me. Since he has your question in the inbox don't worry.